# Subsetting columns from a dataframe to create new dataframes by iteration

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have a large dataframe and want to create several new dataframes from individual columns. Each new dataframe should consist of the first two columns plus one of the next columns.

I can do this manually; my desired dummy products being `subA`, `subB`, and `subC`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# dummy dataframe
chr1 <- letters[1:4]
chr2 <- letters[23:26]
A <- 1:4
B <- 5:8
C <- 9:12
data <- tibble(chr1, chr2, A, B, C)

# manual subsetting
subA <- data %>%
  select(chr1, chr2, A)

subB <- data %>%
  select(chr1, chr2, B)

subC <- data %>%
  select(chr1, chr2, C)
```

However, my original dataframe has about 700 columns, so I am looking for some kind of simple iteration, preferably in tidyverse (purrr), that is flexible enough to be supplemented by pipes into additional functions.

Comment: `map(names(data)[3:length(names(data))], ~ select(data, chr1, chr2, all_of(.x)))`

Comment: `imap(select(data, A:C), ~ select(data, chr1, chr2, !! .y))`

Comment: Thanks! Both lines work nicely, and I like how @LMc's code keeps the column names. Great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `base`:

```r
lapply(split.default(data[-c(1,2)], names(data[-c(1,2)])), function(x) 
        cbind(data[c(1,2)], x))
```

or in `tidyverse`:

```r
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(1, 2)) %>% 
  split(., .$name) %>% 
  map(., ~pivot_wider(.x))
```

```
#> $A
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   chr1  chr2      A
#>   <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1 a     w         1
#> 2 b     x         2
#> 3 c     y         3
#> 4 d     z         4
#> 
#> $B
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   chr1  chr2      B
#>   <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1 a     w         5
#> 2 b     x         6
#> 3 c     y         7
#> 4 d     z         8
#> 
#> $C
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   chr1  chr2      C
#>   <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1 a     w         9
#> 2 b     x        10
#> 3 c     y        11
#> 4 d     z        12
```

If you want to save these as individual dataframes:

```r
list2env(
    lapply(split.default(data[-c(1,2)], paste0("sub", names(data[-c(1,2)]))), function(x) 
           cbind(data[c(1,2)], x)),  
    envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend reading my answer at [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) for some perspective about using lists.

You could can make a list of your results like this:

```
chr_cols = c("chr1", "chr2")
sub_cols = setdiff(names(data), chr_cols)
result = lapply(sub_cols, \(x) data[c(chr_cols, x)])
names(result) = paste0("sub", sub_cols)
```

Then if you really want you could do `list2env(result)` to copy those sub data frames from the `result` list to your global environment, but I'd recommend against it.

Franky, I'd recommend against the first step too... I don't know what you're doing next but you very likely don't need to copy your data this many times first.

Comment: Thanks here, too. There's one closing bracket too much. After removing it, this works, too.  And I guess, it should be "sub_cols" instead of "chr_cols" in the last line.
Why is it so much longer than the code above?

Comment: Fixed the typos. It's a little longer than above to make it more readable and because I give the result the names you ask for in the question and I define the column groups on separate lines without relying on column indices--I think this makes it more robust and easier to debug. It could be condensed of course, I find the code less readable but if you would rather type less character you could do `lapply(data[-(1:2), \(x) cbind(data[1:2], x))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

imap(select(data, A:C), ~ select(data, chr1, chr2, !! .y))
```

Instead of using the `!!` injection (which injects the expression before `select` runs so that `!! .y` evaluates to `A` in the first iteration, `B` in the second and so on), you could use the `dplyr` function `all_of` which takes a character vector of column names (`all_of(.y)`). This is what @Phil uses in his comment.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is great, too. If I could accept two most helpful answers, I'd tick this one, too.